# Get empty result when trying to get filterable attribute for particular category

Tags: magento-1, filter, soap, layer

I need to retrieve all filterable attributes for category. I'm using that snippet:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$layer = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer');

$layer->setCurrentCategory($category);

$attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();//$attributes now is empty array
```

Category has product with filterable attributes, also in categories options anchor was enabled. This code using in SOAP API.

Maybe someone know where I made mistake?

Comment: Try to `var_dump($category)` to see if everything is okay in general.

Comment: You might asking the same thing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157799/magento-get-filterable-attributes-by-category

Comment: I can't use var_dump because it's code for api and it return only values defined in wsdl.xml file. But I check category by pass it to one of this value. Category model is OK, and it seting to layer correct, and I can get it back by $layer->getCurrentCategory();P

Comment: You can try to add `Mage::log($collection->getSelect(), Zend_Log::INFO, 'blah.log', true);` in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php` -> `public function getFilterableAttributes()` before `return` and to run logged SQL query directly in the database or to compare it with the SQL query that is logged when you open the category through the site.

Comment: getFilterableAttributes() return empty array because $setIds = $this->_getSetIds() return empty array. It happen because $this->getProductCollection() return empty collection. Maybe something else needed fo $layer to get product collection from it?

Comment: @Quickerz were you able to solve this problem? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you didn't set the store id, we need to do so since it's implemented in the api:

```
protected function _retrieve(){

    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $store_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store_id');

    $category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($id);        
    $category->setStoreId($store_id);

    if (!($category->getId())) $this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND);

    $layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
    $attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();
```

Answer (score 0):

following code is used to get filterable attributes and their options

```
$categoryId = '5'; // replace with your category id
$category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($categoryId);
$layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
$layer->setCurrentCategory($category);

$setIds = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
            ->load($attrSetName, 'attribute_set_name')
            ->getAttributeSetId();

$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
$attributes->setItemObjectClass('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')
                ->setAttributeSetFilter($setIds)
                ->addStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->setOrder('position', 'ASC');


$attributes->addFieldToFilter('additional_table.is_filterable', array('gt' => 0));
$attributes->load();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    $filter_attr = array();
    $filter_attr['title'] = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
    $filter_attr['code'] = $attribute->getAttributeCode();

    if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'price') {
        $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_price';
    }elseif ($attribute->getBackendType() == 'decimal') {
        $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_decimal';
    }else {
        $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_attribute';
    }

    $result =  Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setLayer($layer)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init();
    $i=0;

    foreach($result->getItems() as $option) {
        $attr_option = array();
        if($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'price') {
            $attr_option['label'] = str_replace(array('<span class="price">','</span>'),'',$option->getLabel());
        } else {
            $attr_option['label'] = $option->getLabel();
        }

        $attr_option['value'] = $option->getValue();
        $attr_option['count'] = $option->getCount();
        $i++;
        $filter_attr['options'][] = $attr_option;
    }

    if($i!=0){
        $filter_attributes[] = $filter_attr;
    }
}
```